# Having trouble understanding a solution to this c# algorithm

Tags: c#

I was doing a LeetCode exercise for c# and made my own solution for the following prompt:
"Given a binary array nums, return the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the array."

"Input: nums = [1,1,0,1,1,1]
Output: 3
Explanation: The first two digits or the last three digits are consecutive 1s. The maximum number of consecutive 1s is 3."

My solution had a hardcoded array value, and i found a solution online that worked and ran fine. However, im having a really hard time understanding what the isStart and isEnd bools do. The code is below:

```
public class Solution {
    public int FindMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums)
        {
            if(nums == null || nums.Length == 0)
            {
                return 0; 
            }

            var start = 0;            

            var length = nums.Length;
            var maxLength = 0; 
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                var current = nums[i];
                bool isStart = current == 1 && (i == 0 || nums[i - 1] == 0);
                bool isEnd   = current == 1 && (i == length - 1 || nums[i + 1] == 0);

                if (isStart)
                {
                    start = i;
                }

                if(isEnd)
                {
                    var currentOnes = i - start + 1;
                    maxLength = currentOnes > maxLength ? currentOnes : maxLength;
                }
            }

            return maxLength;
        }
```

I assume isStart and isEnd determine if we are at the Start or End of the array? I dont really understand what the operators do either. Any help could be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you doing this exercise?

Comment: Code looks pretty simple to me and the variables are named well. They are true when the value at `nums[i]` is the start or end of a sequence.

Comment: `isStart = current == 1 && (i == 0 || nums[i - 1] == 0)` => `isStart = [this is a 1] and ([beginning of the array] or [previous element was zero])`. eg `isStart = [is this the start of a sequence of 1's]`